# Can't get 'this' in node.js object prototype function

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to wrap some of my codes into node module but there is a problem occurred.

My testing code:

```
var Twitter_Client = require('./src/twitter-client');

var twitterClient = new Twitter_Client({
        consumer_key : '',
        consumer_secret : '',
        access_token_key : '',
        access_token_secret : ''
    });

twitterClient.tweet([{path: 'some_path', type: 'image/jpg'}],'test');
```

My module looks like this:

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require("bluebird");

function Twitter_Client(opts){
    if (!(this instanceof Twitter_Client))
    return new Twitter_Client(opts);
    this._client = new Twitter(opts);
    this._tray = [];
}

Twitter_Client.prototype.makePost = (endpoint, params)=>{
    ...
};

Twitter_Client.prototype.uploadMedia = (path, type)=>{
    ...
};

Twitter_Client.prototype.tweet = (medias, status)=>{
    var that = this;
    console.log(this instanceof Twitter_Client);
    return (()=>{
        if (!Array.isArray(medias) || medias.length == 0) {
            return Promise.resolve([]);
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(medias).map((media) => {
                return that.uploadMedia(media.path, media.type);
            });
        }
    })().then((mediaids) => {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            that._client.post('statuses/update', {
                status : status,
                media_ids : mediaids.join(',')
            }, function (error, tweet, response) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
                resolve(tweet);
            });
        });

    });
};

module.exports = Twitter_Client;
```

There are three functions of this module but it will be too long if I post all so I am only showing one of those which is called by the testing code.
When I run the code above it gives me:

```
false
Unhandled rejection TypeError: that.uploadMedia is not a function
```

It seems that I am not getting a correct object from 'this'.
I have read many similar question and seems that I am creating an object in a right way and calling the function from the object instead of the instance.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Try using `function() {}` instead of the arrow syntax `() => {}`

Comment: Agree with @user2896976, it's either typescript or es6 - and in both cases arrow function must be the reason. "that" will point to the *module*, not *Twitter_Client*.

Comment: @ctw This is a good explanation for what's happening. Read the "No separate this" section. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions

Comment: @user2896976 Thanks for your referencing link and I used `function() {}` instead to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining methods as fat arrow functions.  Because of the way fat arrow functions work, that means that the `this` value comes from the local context in your module, NOT from the object that you called the method on.  So, change this:

```
Twitter_Client.prototype.tweet = (medias, status)=>{
```

to this:

```
Twitter_Client.prototype.tweet = function(medias, status){
```

And, change all your other methods too.  This is one place that fat arrow functions should never be used because they explicitly break the `this` value for object methods.

---

FYI, since it looks like you're using Bluebird promises, you can change this:

```
        return Promise.resolve(medias).map((media) => {
            return that.uploadMedia(media.path, media.type);
        });
```

to this:

```
        return Promise.map(medias, (media) => {
            return that.uploadMedia(media.path, media.type);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of the problem and point out one more problem of my code. It works now.

Comment: Oh sorry I am being quite new here. I have checked the mark now.

Comment: @ctw - No problem, just helping new folks understand how it works.